# The gem I compiled broke my app, makes it so all the models are uninitialized contants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The [deep_cloning gem](https://github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning) is causing this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant %{AnyModel}
```

When I do bundle update, it tells me this:

```
deep_cloning at /Users/me! =D/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@secret_gemset/bundler/gems/deep_cloning-423f1e30eeef did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["deep_cloning-0.2.0.gem"] are not files
```

What am I doing wrong here?

In my Gemfile I specify the path to the gem like so:

```
gem "deep_cloning", :git => "git://github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning.git"
```

Update: the stacktrace from the unitialized constant error:

```
> MyModel.find(455)
NameError: uninitialized constant MyModel
    from /rvm_gemset_path/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /rvm_gemset_path/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `rake_original_const_missing'
    from /rvm_gemset_path/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
    from /rvm_gemset_path/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the line :

```
s.files = [
...
     "deep_cloning-0.2.0.gem"
...
]
```

from your gemspec.

Comment: that fixed the bundler update error! =D but all my models are still unitialized constants =\

Comment: Could you add the exception backtrace ?

Comment: sure can, updating Question now.

Comment: Any reason you defined an empty `self.included` ?

Comment: oh, hey, when I start the console, it says that ActiveRecord and ApplicationController are unitialized Constants.